# iText not showing all HTML elements

Tags: java, html, itext, pdf-generation

I'm building a PDF file from many HTML portions using Java and iText 5.

I know it's an old version of iText, but we have another PDF file where we attach an audio (ogg file) and we couldn't make it work on new versions. Any help on this would also be appreciated :)

So, the issue, I have an HTML piece like this:

```
<span>
  <p>Some text <strong>with bold</strong></p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
  <p>Third paragraph <br /> with a line break</p>
  <img src="..." alt="Image file" />
</span>
```

In Java I do this:

```
ElementList list2 = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(htmlString, null);
Paragraph htmlPiece= new Paragraph();
for (Element element2 : list2) {
  htmlPiece.add(element2);
}
htmlPiece.setMultipliedLeading(1);
htmlPiece.setIndentationLeft(50f);
document.add(htmlPiece);
```

The problem is that some HTML tags (strong, ul, ol) show perfectly on the PDF, but others (p, br, img) don't work. They just disappear and everything shows on a single line in the resulting PDF file.

Any advice on how to make it work? Or at least, what is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with this version so far, so I am not sure exactly why it is working for some tags only.

```
Paragraph htmlPiece= new Paragraph();
try(StringReader reader = new StringReader(htmlString)) {
    java.util.List<Element> list2 = com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.parseToList(reader, null);
    for (Element element : list2) {
      htmlPiece.add(element);
    }
}
htmlPiece.setMultipliedLeading(1);
htmlPiece.setIndentationLeft(50f);
document.add(htmlPiece);
```

I have added XML Worker dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.tool/xmlworker -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, HTMLWorker is deprecated, so use the latest version of XMLWorker as below

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(new ElementHandler() {
    @Override
    public void add(Writable w) {
        if (w instanceof WritableElement) {
          List<Element> elements = ((WritableElement) w).elements();
          for (Element e : elements) {
            htmlPiece.add(e);
          }
        }
    }
}, reader);
```

These are written in iText 5.4.0, there will be some changes in syntax. do check that also
Try this piece of code and let me know if it's works

Comment: Hi!
Adding elements to a cell and then the cell to the paragraph throws an exception:
```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Insertion of illegal Element: 30
 at com.itextpdf.text.Phrase.add(Phrase.java:371)
 at com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph.add(Paragraph.java:347)
```

And adding the cell to the document directly doesn't show anything on the resulting PDF.

Any other hints? 

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry. Could you share your iText version? I was able to solve work all tags including img tag on 5.4.0 version

Comment: The version I'm working on is 5.5.11, installed through Maven in a Springboot application

Comment: @IñigoGorosabel Updated answer.